# Find $r$ given that: $M=aY + B(r-x)^{-c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation like so:

> $M=aY + B(r-x)^{-c}$

Assuming all the variables are positive, how do I find $r$? I've worked it out to about this point:

$M(r-x)^c=aY(r-x)^c+B$

$r-x=\sqrt[c]{\frac{aY(r-x)^c+B}{M}}$

$r=\sqrt[c]{\frac{aY(r-x)^c+B}{M}}+x$

But I don't think this is right considering there's still $(r-x)^c$ on the right hand side?

Comment: $$M(r-x)^{c} = aY(r-x)^{c} + B \iff (M - aY)(r-x)^{c} = B \iff (r-x)^{c} = \frac{B}{M - aY}$$

Comment: Is this even a differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$M=aY + B(r-x)^{-c}\\\frac {M-aY}B=(r-x)^{-c}\\\frac B{M-aY}=(r-x)^c\\
\sqrt[c]{\frac B{M-aY}}=r-x\\x+\sqrt[c]{\frac B{M-aY}}=r$$

Comment: Yikes I'm rusty, thanks a lot :)